# Page Layout and Site Template Settings - Properties using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, client-object-model, csom

I have a requirement where I need to access the `Site Templates` and `Page Layouts` and the `Default Page layout`. I'm able to access all the properties using

```
$web.AllProperties["__WebTemplates"]
$web.AllProperties["__PageLayouts"]
$web.AllProperties["__DefaultPageLayout"]
```

I was able to update all the 3 properties. But I'm unable to update the `Reset all subsites to inherit these preferred subsite template settings` and `Reset all subsites to inherit these preferred page layout settings`.

Can anyone help me with the properties of the above? I need to make the checkbox checked true using PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it via the UI and then inspect how the web properties have changed. My guess is, they disappear altogether. So, remove the web properties.